# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ReactAndroid" with any of the following names: ReactAndroidConfig.cmake

Tags: android, react-native, google-mlkit, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to configure `react-native-reanimated` in my React Native project and I had to install `vision-camera-code-scanner`. At the beginning, I was getting an error when building the project due to react-native-reanimated issue. After solving this issue, I got another issue in vision-camera-code-scanner that you can check in update section.

First I was getting an error during build when it is executed `node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/CmakeLists.txt` on line `find_package(ReactAndroid REQUIRED CONFIG)`. The following error is displayed:

```
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
C/C++: C:\Github\bcgov\IAS\ReactNativeProject\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt debug|x86 : com.google.prefab.api.NoMatchingLibraryException: No compatible library found for //ReactAndroid/fabricjni. Rejected the following libraries:
[CXX1214] C:\Github\bcgov\IAS\ReactNativeProject\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt debug|x86 : User has minSdkVersion 19 but library was built for 21 [//ReactAndroid/fabricjni]
C/C++: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package):
C/C++:   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ReactAndroid" with
C/C++:   any of the following names:
C/C++:     ReactAndroidConfig.cmake
C/C++:     reactandroid-config.cmake
C/C++:   Add the installation prefix of "ReactAndroid" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
C/C++:   "ReactAndroid_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
C/C++:   "ReactAndroid" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
C/C++:   has been installed.

[CXX1429] error when building with cmake using C:\ReactNative\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt: -- Android: Targeting API '16' with architecture 'x86', ABI 'x86', and processor 'i686'
-- Android: Selected unified Clang toolchain
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 12.0.8
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 12.0.8
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/JohnBarton/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/JohnBarton/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- REACT_NATIVE_DIR="C:/ReactNative/node_modules/react-native"
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/ReactNative/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/Debug/2c4a4j6q/x86/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

This is my configuration:

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-shared-group-preferences": "^1.1.23",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^3.3.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
```

android.gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
hermesEnabled=true
```

Searching on react-native folder, I can find the following:

```
PS C:\ReactNative\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\cmake-utils> dir


    Directory: C:\ReactNative\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\cmake-utils  


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2023-10-04  10:09 AM                default-app-setup
-a----        2023-10-04  10:09 AM            773 folly-flags.cmake
-a----        2023-10-04  10:09 AM           6555 ReactNative-application.cmake
```

But I am not finding `ReactAndroidConfig.cmake` nor `reactandroid-config.cmake` is this a file I have to create manually? What would be the content?

**Update**

Found out that the above error was related to `minSdkVersion` defined under node_modules/react_native_reanimated/android/build.gradle on line 265:

```
minSdkVersion safeExtGet("minSdkVersion", 16)
```

I updated to 21:

```
minSdkVersion safeExtGet("minSdkVersion", 21)
```

After updating the minSdkVersion the build is successful. With the following warning:

```
Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
Affected Modules: react-native-reanimated
```

However, when running the project, I am getting the following error related to `com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode` package:

```
> Task :vision-camera-code-scanner:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\ReactNative\node_modules\vision-camera-code-scanner\android\src\main\java\com\visioncameracodescanner\BarcodeConverter.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class Barcode
  location: package com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode
C:\ReactNative\\node_modules\vision-camera-code-scanner\android\src\main\java\com\visioncameracodescanner\BarcodeConverter.java:49: error: package Barcode does not exist
  public static WritableNativeArray convertAddressList(@NonNull List<Barcode.Address> addresses) {
                                                                            ^
C:\ReactNative\\node_modules\vision-camera-code-scanner\android\src\main\java\com\visioncameracodescanner\BarcodeConverter.java:59: error: package Barcode does not exist
  public static WritableNativeArray convertPhoneList(@NonNull List<Barcode.Phone> phones) {
                                                                          ^
C:\ReactNative\\node_modules\vision-camera-code-scanner\android\src\main\java\com\visioncameracodescanner\BarcodeConverter.java:69: error: package Barcode does not exist
  public static WritableNativeArray convertEmailList(@NonNull List<Barcode.Email> emails) {
```

Checking the version of vision-camera-code-scanner is [2 years old](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vision-camera-code-scanner?activeTab=versions). However, it seems that the dependency `google mlkit` changed?

Thanks in advance for your guidance :)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Stuck with a similar error

Comment: I changed to use https://github.com/teslamotors/react-native-camera-kit. Following the instructions is very straightforward.